# How to continue execution after exception in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, exception

Hi have a function that imports new users from a CSV file.
If the password field for a user is empty, I get a
**Cartalyst \ Sentry \ Users \ PasswordRequiredException**

I am trying to catch this exception and storing the message to a session variable, but I want to continue importing the rest of the users after the exception has happened.

Currently I am using this handler:

```
App::error(function(Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $exception)
{
    Session::push('import.errors', $exception->getMessage());
});
```

Using XDebug I have determined that the handler is triggered - but execution also stops after the error.

How can I continue importing the rest of the users in the CSV?

Comment: where you add users in to a csv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the exception where your function imports new users, then you can choose to ignore it:

```
your_import_function($users_to_be_imported)
{
     foreach ($users_to_be_imported as $user) {
         try {
             // Import user code here
         } catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\PasswordRequiredException $exception) {
             // Log user that failed here
         }
     }
 }
```

Because you are catching the exception in your function - it should not 'bubble' up to the `App::error()` function

Comment: Ok thanks, that make sense. I will try it. I just thought there was a different way since it would be nice to keep the exception handling code out of my method - seems as if it would be cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: It would be nice to do what you were trying @slickorange, but we have to write a lot of try/catch